# How do I refer to absolute change in 2 percentages?

Tags: percentages

I'm writing a paper and I have `45% WER` (word error rate) under one condition. Under a different condition, that improves to a `34% WER`. It seems incorrect to say that I had an `11% improvement in WER`. What would be the correct way to state this?

Comment: markup and margin.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: 11/45= ? % that's your decrease in error.

Comment: So would I say that I had a 24% reduction in WER?

Comment: correct except it's 24 and 4/9 %

Comment: you could also look at 11/55= 1/5= 20% more words correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say, that:

- The error has decreased by $11$ percentage points

or

- The error has decreased by $24.4\%$

Comment: The second of those may still confuse some people who interpret it as the first.

Comment: that's why stores have sales @Henry

Comment: you could also look at 11/55= 1/5= 20% more words correct.

Comment: Where did you get 55 from?